# Take API data and display it on a webpage using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, api, html

Hi guys I am new to making websites and wanted to use nodejs.

I am using an API to get data with this in node:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

When I run it in node it displays the output that I want, but how can I use this data and display it to a webpage or alter HTML with it? I am VERY new so please explain everything :<

Comment: What is your output when you log body?

Answer (score 1):

You should use templating engines for that. Following sample uses *[ejs](http://ejs.co/)* with [express.js](https://expressjs.com/)

```
  var express = require('express')
  var app = express();

  app.set("view engine", "ejs");

  // This assumes your project has a directory named 'views' in it.
  app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

  app.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res){
      var templateValues = {
        title: 'Sample title',
        result_code: 900,
        body_text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...'
      }

      // Your template file should be in 'your-project-name/views/home.ejs'
      res.render("home", templateValues);
    }
```

In your `home.ejs`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title><%= title  %></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= body_text  %>

  </body>
</html>
```

This will display an HTML page with title **Sample title** and text **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...**. Modify `templateValues` with your variables and you're all set.

*Checkout another example in [here](https://medium.com/@bhanushali.mahesh3/creating-a-simple-website-with-node-js-express-and-ejs-view-engine-856382a4578f)*